# Labeling GoogleMaps Lat/Lng intersection

Tags: javascript, google-maps, label

I create a map with latitude and longitude lines drawn every 1/4 min.  The resulting boxes are called Quarter Minutes.  I need to label each Quarter Minute box.  The label should be the lat/lon of the SW corner inside the box.  Since I draw all the latitude lines within the viewing area first, and then all the longitude lines, I cannot figure out how to find the intersect point.  It would seem, that I would draw one(1) latitude line, and then one(1) longitude line and then label the intersect.  I figure I can just use an info box at each point.

I do not know how to do this in JavaScript.  Maybe it is not necessary to trap the intersection at the point of creation but that is the only way I would think it would happen.

```
The syntax for a QtrMin is 
3040A8415A = intersect at 30 40' by 84 15'
3040A8415B = intersect at 30 40' by 84 15' 15"
3040A8415C = intersect at 30 40' by 84 15' 30"
3040A8415D = intersect at 30 40' by 84 15' 45"

or DDMM and A-> D to designate each quarter of minute.
Longitude and latitude are treated the same.
```

What I have is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;libraries=geometry&amp;sensor=false"></script>
    <title>Find your Qtr minute locator</title>
</head>
<body style="height:100%;margin:0">
<!-- Declare the div, make it take up the full document body -->
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var map;

    var llOffset = 0.0666666666666667;
    var drawGridBox = false;

    var gridOverBox = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: [],
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '',
        strokeOpacity: 0,
        strokeWeight: 0
    });

    var gridline;
    var polylinesquare;
    var latPolylines = [];

    var lngPolylines = [];
    var smLngPolylines = [];
    var lngLabels = [];
    var lngMapLabel;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.00, -84.00),
            zoom: 10,
            streetViewControl: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scaleControl: true
        });


        DrawGridOn();
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {
            createGridLines(map.getBounds());
        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    function DrawGridOn() {
        drawGridBox = true;
    }

    function DrawGridOff() {
        drawGridBox = false;
    }



    function createGridLines(bounds) {
        for (var i = 0; i < latPolylines.length; i++) {
            latPolylines[i].setMap(null);
        }

        latPolylines = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < lngPolylines.length; i++) {
            lngPolylines[i].setMap(null);
        }
        lngPolylines = [];

        if (map.getZoom() < 10) return;
        var north = bounds.getNorthEast().lat();
        var east  = bounds.getNorthEast().lng();
        var south = bounds.getSouthWest().lat();
        var west  = bounds.getSouthWest().lng();

        // define the size of the grid
        var topLat = Math.ceil(north / llOffset) * llOffset;
        var rightLong = Math.ceil(east / llOffset) * llOffset;

        var bottomLat = Math.floor(south / llOffset) * llOffset;
        var leftLong = Math.floor(west / llOffset) * llOffset;

        for (var latitude = bottomLat; latitude <= topLat; latitude += llOffset) latPolylines.push(new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, leftLong), new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, rightLong)],
            map: map,
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: '#0000FF',
            strokeOpacity: 0.5,
            strokeWeight: 1
        }));
        for (var longitude = leftLong; longitude <= rightLong; longitude += llOffset) lngPolylines.push(new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(topLat, longitude), new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLat, longitude)],
            map: map,
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: '#0000FF',
            strokeOpacity: 0.5,
            strokeWeight: 1
        }));
    }

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you seen [Bill Chadwick's  WGS84 Lat/Lon Graticules for the V3 Maps API](http://www.bdcc.co.uk/Gmaps/ll_grat_v3_demo.htm)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Maybe it is not necessary to trap the intersection at the point of creation but that is the only way I would think it would happen*

You draw straight lines with either equal latitudes or longitudes, so you may assume that the intersection of 2 lines:

```
latLine a: ay1,ax1 ay1,ax2
lngLine b: by1,bx1 by2,bx1
```

...is `ay1,bx1`

When the lines have been created iterate over them and create the labels based on the latitudes/longitudes:

```
    //put the next 4 lines to the top of createGridLines 
    for(var i=0;i<lngLabels.length;++i){
     lngLabels[i].setMap(null);
    }
    lngLabels=[];

    //put this at the end of createGridLines
    for(var x=0;x<latPolylines.length;++x){
      for(var y=0;y<lngPolylines.length-1;++y){
        var latLng=new google.maps.LatLng(latPolylines[x].getPath().getAt(0).lat(),
                                          lngPolylines[y].getPath().getAt(0).lng());

        lngLabels.push(new google.maps.Marker({
          map:map,
          position:latLng,
          icon:{  url:'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?'
                        +'chst=d_bubble_text_small&chld=bb|'
                        + latLng.toUrlValue()
                        +'|FFFFFF|000000',
                  anchor:new google.maps.Point(0,42)
                }
          }));
      }
    }
```

Comment: Holle Molle,
I think you got it.  Mentally, I was thinking of a similar solution but my JS is too infantile.  If I were writing this in C or Pascal, it is how I would have done it.  Thanks much!